# Android - Extra-weird uncaught exception on a basic activity

Tags: android

I can't figure out what it is going on here...after hours...

This is the activity in question (that I have made super-easy in order to narrow down the problem):

```
public class UserAuthenticationActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.e("MYAPP", "step1");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.user_authentication);
        Log.e("MYAPP", "step2");
    }

    @Override    
    public void onStart()
    {
        super.onStart();
    }
}
```

And this is layout/user_authentication:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"    
        android:padding="15sp"
        >  

    <TextView  
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="hello!"
        android:paddingTop="15sp"  
        android:paddingBottom="5sp"    
        android:textSize="15sp"        
        />    

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

I get the error screen when I launch the application. The log doesn't show my debug messages but just this exception:

```
I/ActivityManager( 1032): Starting activity: Intent { comp={com.myapp.android.app/com.myapp.android.app.activity.UserAuthenticationActivity} }
D/Database( 1990): hook db is called for:/data/data/com.myapp.android.app/databases/myappDatabase.db
D/Database( 1990): hook not enabled for /data/data/com.myapp.android.app/databases/myappDatabase.db
E/QC-DSS-LIB(  981): unrecognized ifindex 6
W/dalvikvm( 1990): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4000fe70)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1990): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
E/AndroidRuntime( 1990): java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime( 1990):    at android.widget.ListView.measureScrapChild(ListView.java:1039)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1990):    at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1120)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1990):    at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1031)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1990):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:7236)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1990):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:2875)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1990):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:888)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1990):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:350)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1990):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:278)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1990):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:7236)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1990):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:2875)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1990):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:245)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1990):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:7236)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1990):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:464)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1990):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:278)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1990):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:7236)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1990):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:2875)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1990):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:245)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1990):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:7236)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1990):    at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:698)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1990):    at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1482)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1990):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1990):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1990):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3948)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1990):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1990):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1990):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:782)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1990):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:540)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1990):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I hope somebody can help me. I don't have any clue.

Thanks,
Dan

Comment: Why is `Database` being logged if it's not being called from your Activity? Check your AndroidManifest for any duplicate entries or anything weird (or post it here), and let us know how you're launching this Activity.

Comment: Christopher, good points! This activity is explicitly launched by the activity ListActivity. I guess ListActivity doesn't close a db connection that it opened. Probably the Database log entry is triggered by the ListActivity activity rather than the UserAuthenticationActivity. I am having a look to the db connections flow.

Comment: Given that `ListView` is in the stack trace and you're coming from some type of `ListActivity`, it sounds like that's the cause of the problem. Are you doing something odd in `onPause()` or `onDestroy()` in the list activity, or running a thread in that activity that updates the list somehow?

Comment: I have fixed it: I have added 'return true' after    startActivity(intent); in the ListActivity::onCreate method. Probably you should always add a return statement after startActivity(intent). Isn't it? Thanks a lot, Christopher!

Comment: It depends on the exact code. Sounds like you're doing something relatively complex in onCreate (like calling startActivity from a click handler?), since normally you wouldn't call startActivity inside onCreate directly. Anyway, glad it's sorted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could it be because there is no contentview?

Further points of interest:

- There are several Views in your scrollview, but it can have only one child (use something like a linear layout to put more than 1 in there)
- How does your manifest look? What activities are declared there? (or, as @kcoppock said: is this your only activity?)
- Why is it throwing stuff from .widget? What are you using in e.g. imports?

Comment: I have tried to add that (I have edited my original post too) but it doesn't make any difference.

Comment: @dan: Is this your only Activity and XML layout?

Comment: You are misreading that XML: there is only one direct child of the `ScrollView`.

Comment: You're absolutely right, My bad! Hmm. that only leaves the random points of interest, sorry :) (i've deleted the nonsense to leave an actual usefull answer)