# My app Showing Unfortunately stopped error

Tags: android

Hi team have developed an application called AutoDial in which it is running successfully in
all android device and in samsung devices it not working properly so please help me out to solve from this problem.

Here is my logcat:

```
04-09 10:32:12.521: I/log(5166): maaaap{}
04-09 10:32:12.543: D/GPS Enabled(5166): GPS Enabled
04-09 10:32:12.543: I/System.out(5166): inside location manager
04-09 10:32:12.546: D/AndroidRuntime(5166): Shutting down VM
04-09 10:32:12.547: W/dalvikvm(5166): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x416c8d40)
04-09 10:32:12.548: E/AndroidRuntime(5166): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-09 10:32:12.548: E/AndroidRuntime(5166): Process: com.example.gpstracking, PID: 5166
04-09 10:32:12.548: E/AndroidRuntime(5166): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-09 10:32:12.548: E/AndroidRuntime(5166):     at com.example.gpstracking.AndroidGPSTrackingActivity$1$1$1.run(AndroidGPSTrackingActivity.java:169)
04-09 10:32:12.548: E/AndroidRuntime(5166):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
04-09 10:32:12.548: E/AndroidRuntime(5166):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
04-09 10:32:12.548: E/AndroidRuntime(5166):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
04-09 10:32:12.548: E/AndroidRuntime(5166):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5102)
04-09 10:32:12.548: E/AndroidRuntime(5166):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-09 10:32:12.548: E/AndroidRuntime(5166):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
04-09 10:32:12.548: E/AndroidRuntime(5166):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
04-09 10:32:12.548: E/AndroidRuntime(5166):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
04-09 10:32:12.548: E/AndroidRuntime(5166):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here is my code and tell me what all changes i need to do in this snippet.

```
package com.example.gpstracking;


import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import java.util.TreeMap;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;



public class AndroidGPSTrackingActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener 
{

    Button btnShowLocation;
    Button btnWriteSDFile;
    Button btnClose;
    EditText txtData;
    GPSTracker gps;
    private Spinner spinner1, spinner2;
      private Button btnSubmit;

        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);

            addItemsOnSpinner2();
            checkExternalMedia();
            writeToExternalTextFile();
            readfromFilesms();
            addListenerOnButton();
            addListenerOnSpinnerItemSelection();
            LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

            if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER))
            {
                Toast.makeText(this, "GPS is Enabled in your devide", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else
            {
                showGPSDisabledAlertToUser();
            }
                btnShowLocation = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnShowLocation);
                btnShowLocation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
                {

                    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
                    public void onClick(View v)     
                    {
                        Context c = getApplicationContext();
                        SharedPreferences app_preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(c);
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = app_preferences.edit();
                        TimerTask scanTask;
                        final Handler handler = new Handler();
                        Timer t = new Timer();
                        scanTask = new TimerTask() 
                        {
                            GPSTracker gps;
                            List<Double> l = new ArrayList<Double>();
                            TreeMap<Double,List<Double>> list = new  TreeMap<Double,List<Double>>();
                             public void run() 
                             {
                                    handler.post(new Runnable() 
                                    {


                                        public void run() 
                                        {
                                                    Context c = getApplicationContext();
                                                    SharedPreferences app_preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(c);
                                                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = app_preferences.edit();
                                                    int counter = app_preferences.getInt("counter", 0);
                                                    Log.i("log", "maaaap"+list);
                                                    Double latitude=new Double(0.0d);
                                                    Double longitude=new Double(0.0d);
                                                    l = new ArrayList<Double>();
                                                    gps = new GPSTracker(AndroidGPSTrackingActivity.this);

                                                    if(gps.canGetLocation())
                                                    {

                                                         l.add(gps.getLatitude());
                                                         l.add(gps.getLongitude());
                                                         list.put(gps.getAccur(),l);
                                                         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your Location is - \nLat: " + gps.getLatitude() + "\nLong:" + gps.getLongitude()+ "\nAccracy:"+gps.getAccur(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                                        Log.i("log", "latitude"+gps.getLatitude());
                                                        Log.i("log", "longitude"+gps.getLongitude());
                                                        Log.i("log", "gps.getAccur()"+gps.getAccur());
                                                        Log.d("tag", "Finding Latitude");
                                                        latitude = gps.getLatitude();
                                                        Log.d("tag", "Lat: "+String.valueOf(latitude));
                                                        Log.d("tag", "Finding Longitude");
                                                        longitude  = gps.getLongitude();
                                                        Log.d("tag", "Lon: "+String.valueOf(longitude));
                                                        String Text =
                                                        "\nLat: " + gps.getLatitude() +
                                                        "\nLan:" + gps.getLongitude()+"\nAcrcy="+gps.getAccur();

                                                        sendSMS(readfromFilesms(), Text);

                                                    }
                                                    else
                                                    {

                                                    }

                                                if(counter<12)
                                                {
                                                    if(gps.getAccur()<=3)
                                                    {
                                                        Double  d =  (Double)list.firstKey();
                                                        Log.i("log", "gps.firstKey()"+d);

                                                        List<?> l1 = (List<?>)list.get(d);
                                                        Log.i("log", "gps.l1()"+(Double)l1.get(0));
                                                        Log.i("log", "gps.l2"+(Double)l1.get(1));
                                                        latitude = (Double)l1.get(0);
                                                        longitude = (Double)l1.get(1);
                                                        editor.putInt("counter", 0);
                                                        editor.commit(); // Very important
                                                        cancel();

                                                    }
                                                    else
                                                    {
                                                        counter = app_preferences.getInt("counter", 0);
                                                        Log.i("log", "counter"+counter);
                                                        editor.putInt("counter", ++counter);
                                                        editor.commit(); 
                                                    }

                                                }
                                                else
                                                {
                                                    Double  d =  (Double)list.firstKey();
                                                    Log.i("log", "gps.firstKey()"+d);

                                                    List<?> l1 = (List<?>)list.get(d);
                                                    Log.i("log", "gps.l1()"+(Double)l1.get(0));
                                                    Log.i("log", "gps.l2"+(Double)l1.get(1));
                                                    latitude = (Double)l1.get(0);
                                                    longitude = (Double)l1.get(1);

                                                    editor.putInt("counter", 0);
                                                    editor.commit(); // Very important
                                                    cancel();

                                                }
                                            }
                                    });
                            }};
                        t.schedule(scanTask,1000,90000000);  
        }
        });
        btnClose = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnClose);
        btnClose.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
        {

            public void onClick(View v) 
            {

                finish();
            }
        }); 
    }
        public void addListenerOnButton() 
        {

                spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);

                spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
                btnSubmit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSubmit);
                btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
                {

                        public void onClick(View v)
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(AndroidGPSTrackingActivity.this,
                            String.valueOf(spinner2.getSelectedItem()),
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            sendSMS(readfromFilesms(),"on leave");
                        }
                });
        }
    private void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message)
    {
        String SENT = "SMS_SENT";
        String DELIVERED = "SMS_DELIVERED";
        PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,new Intent(SENT), 0);
        PendingIntent deliveredPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(DELIVERED), 0);

        registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver()
        {

            public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) 
            {
                switch (getResultCode())
                {
                case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS Sent",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Generic Failure",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No Service",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "null",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Radio off",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
                }
            }
        }, new IntentFilter(SENT));

        registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver()
        {

            public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) 
            {
                switch (getResultCode())
                {
                    case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS Dlivered",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                    case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS not Delivered",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }, new IntentFilter(DELIVERED));
        SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();

        sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, sentPI, deliveredPI);
    }
    private void showGPSDisabledAlertToUser()
    {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("GPS is disabled in your device. Would you like to enable it?")
        .setCancelable(false)
        .setPositiveButton("GPS Setting",
        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id)
            {
                Intent callGPSSettingIntent = new Intent(
                android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                startActivity(callGPSSettingIntent);
            }
        });

        AlertDialog alert = alertDialogBuilder.create();
        alert.show();
    }

    public void addItemsOnSpinner2() {

        spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("Casual Leave");
        list.add("Medical Leave");

        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner2.setAdapter(dataAdapter);



 }


      public void addListenerOnSpinnerItemSelection() 
      {
        spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new CustomOnItemSelectedListener());

        }
      private void checkExternalMedia() 
        {

            @SuppressWarnings("unused")
            boolean mExternalStorageAvailable = false;
            @SuppressWarnings("unused")
            boolean mExternalStorageWriteable = false;
            String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();

            if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) 
            {
                mExternalStorageAvailable = mExternalStorageWriteable = true;
            }   
            else if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(state)) 
            {
              mExternalStorageAvailable = true;
              mExternalStorageWriteable = false;
            } 
            else 
            {
              // Can't read or write
              mExternalStorageAvailable = mExternalStorageWriteable = false;
            }

        }
     private void writeToExternalTextFile() 
        {


            File root = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            File dir = new File(root.getAbsolutePath() + "/PhoneNumber");
            if(!dir.exists())
            dir.mkdirs();
            File file = new File(dir, "PhNumber.txt");
            if (!file.exists ())
            {
                try 
                {
                    FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(file);
                    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(f);
                    pw.flush();
                    pw.close();
                    f.close();
                } 
                catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } 
                catch (IOException e) 
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }
     private String  readfromFilesms() 
     {
            File root = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            Log.i("log", "ddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd"+root.getAbsolutePath());
            File dir = new File(root.getAbsolutePath() + "/PhoneNumber");
            String aBuffer = "";
            File file = new File(dir, "PhNumber.txt");
            if (file.exists ())
            {
                try 
                {
                    FileInputStream fIn = new FileInputStream(file);
                    BufferedReader myReader = new BufferedReader(
                            new InputStreamReader(fIn));
                    String aDataRow = "";
                    while ((aDataRow = myReader.readLine()) != null) 
                    {
                        aBuffer += aDataRow  ;
                    }
                    myReader.close();

                } 
                catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Log.i("TAG",
                            "******* File not found. Did you"
                                    + " add a WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission to the   manifest?");
                } 
                catch (IOException e) 
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return aBuffer;
        }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }



}
```

Hi have one more activity called GpsTracker activity so have to make changes in that also
or what so help me with code snippet.

here is my GpsTracker activity:

```
package com.example.gpstracking;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.util.Log;

public class GPSTracker extends Service implements LocationListener {

    private final Context mContext;


    boolean isGPSEnabled = false;

        boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;


    boolean canGetLocation = false;

    Location location; // location
    double latitude; // latitude
    double longitude; // longitude
    Double accur;

    public Double getAccur() {
        return accur;
    }

    public void setAccur(Double accur) {
        this.accur = accur;
    }


    private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 12; // 10 meters

    // The minimum time between updates in milliseconds
    private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 0; // 1 sec

    // Declaring a Location Manager
    protected LocationManager locationManager;

    public Object getAccuracy;

    public GPSTracker(Context context) {
        this.mContext = context;
        getLocation();
    }

    public Location getLocation() {
        try {
            locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext
                    .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

            // getting GPS status
            isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

            // getting network status
            isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
                    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

            if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
                // no network provider is enabled
            } else {
                this.canGetLocation = true;
                if(isNetworkEnabled){
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES, MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                    Log.d("Network","Network");
                    if(locationManager!=null){
                        location=locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                        if(location!=null){
                            System.out.println("inside location");
                            latitude = location.getLatitude();

                            System.out.println("lat"+latitude);
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (isGPSEnabled) {
                    if (location == null) {

                        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                                LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                                MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                                MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                        Log.d("GPS Enabled","GPS Enabled");

                        if (locationManager != null) {

                            System.out.println("inside location manager");
                            location = locationManager
                                    .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                            if (location != null) {

                                System.out.println("inside location");
                                latitude = location.getLatitude();

                                System.out.println("lat"+latitude);
                                longitude = location.getLongitude();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            if(location!=null)
            {
                setAccur(new Double(location.getAccuracy()));
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return location;
    }


    public double getLatitude(){
        if(location != null){
            latitude = location.getLatitude();
        }

        // return latitude
        return latitude;
    }

    /**
     * Function to get longitude
     * */
    public double getLongitude(){
        if(location != null){
            longitude = location.getLongitude();
        }

        // return longitude
        return longitude;
    }

    /**
     * Function to check GPS/wifi enabled
     * @return boolean
     * */
    public boolean canGetLocation() {
        return this.canGetLocation;
    }

    /**
     * Function to show settings alert dialog
     * On pressing Settings button will lauch Settings Options
     * */
    public void showSettingsAlert(){
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);

        // Setting Dialog Title
        alertDialog.setTitle("GPS is settings");

        // Setting Dialog Message
        alertDialog.setMessage("GPS is not enabled. Do you want to go to settings menu?");

        // On pressing Settings button
        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                mContext.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        // on pressing cancel button
       /* alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();
            }
        });*/

        // Showing Alert Message
        alertDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: Post your code, and point out which is the line 169 of your `AndroidGPSTrackingActivity.java` file.

Comment: You have a NullPointerException @ line 169 `AndroidGPSTrackingActivity.java`. So you need to post the same

Comment: Have used counter to show the location with accuracy

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17685619/how-to-read-android-logcat-android

Answer (score 0):

You are printing the log for:

```
"maaaap" + list
```

at

```
Log.i("log", "maaaap" + list);
```

where `list` is null

So in your `activity`,  under,

```
scanTask = new TimerTask() {
```

for the "`else`" part:

```
Double d = (Double) list.firstKey();
```

`list` is null which throws a NPE.

Add a null pointer check, : `if(list!=null)`  and/or make the "`else`" an "`else if`"

Like inside the last `else`:

```
if(list!=null){
 Double  d =  (Double)list.firstKey();
 Log.i("log", "gps.firstKey()"+d);

 List<?> l1 = (List<?>)list.get(d);
 Log.i("log", "gps.l1()"+(Double)l1.get(0));
 Log.i("log", "gps.l2"+(Double)l1.get(1));
 latitude = (Double)l1.get(0);
 longitude = (Double)l1.get(1);

 editor.putInt("counter", 0);
 editor.commit(); // Very important
 cancel();
    }
```

Please ask another question if your original query has been answered.

For more on NPE,
refer:
http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/java-basics/exceptions/java-lang-nullpointerexception-how-to-handle-null-pointer-exception/

Comment: okie and have one more activity called GpsTracker activity so i need to change that one also or wat

Comment: Am getting same error so tel me now what changes i need to do.

Comment: Need to handle NPE where ever they can arise, so a control flow crash which could be avoided through coding doesn't occur

Comment: Yes, need to add the if condition check over there also

Comment: should i send you whole code with both activities instead

Comment: yeah send whole code with both activities it will be more helpful for me please

Comment: Hai user3500441 please send me corrct code snippet to get thru from ths problem.