# BaseAdapter class wont setAdapter inside Asynctask - Android

Tags: android, string, android-asynctask, baseadapter

I have asynctask that gathers usernames, comments, and numbers. It places them into strings and is then suppose to call a BaseAdapter class, create an adapter, and set the adapter to the class. But my code doesn't work, it crashes the app, here is my code

```
   public class DashboardActivity extends ListActivity {
    String comments[];
    String usernames[];
    String numbers[];
    ListView lstComments;

      class CreateCommentLists extends BaseAdapter{
            Context ctx_invitation;
            String[] listComments;
            String[] listNumbers;
            String[] listUsernames;


            public CreateCommentLists(String[] comments, String[] usernames, String[] numbers)
            {
                super();

                listComments = comments;
                listNumbers = usernames;
                listUsernames = numbers;
            }

            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                if(null == listComments)
                {
                return 0;
                }   

                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return listComments.length;
            }

            @Override
            public Object getItem(int position) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return listComments[position];
            }

            @Override
            public long getItemId(int position) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return 0;
            }

            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                View v = null;
                try
                {
                    String inflater = Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE;
                    LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater)ctx_invitation.getSystemService(inflater);
                    v = li.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);

                    TextView commentView = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.listComment);
                    TextView NumbersView = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.listNumber);
                    TextView usernamesView = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.listPostedBy);


                    commentView.setText(listComments[position]);
                    NumbersView.setText(listNumbers[position]);
                    usernamesView.setText(listUsernames[position]);
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return v;
            }

          }




        class loadComments extends AsyncTask<JSONObject, String, JSONObject> {

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();


            } 

            @Override
            protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
                super.onProgressUpdate(values);

            } 

            protected JSONObject doInBackground(JSONObject... params) {


                JSONObject json2 = CollectComments.collectComments(usernameforcomments, offsetNumber);


                    return json2;



            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json2) {
                try {  
                    if (json2.getString(KEY_SUCCESS) != null) { 
                        registerErrorMsg.setText("");
                        String res2 = json2.getString(KEY_SUCCESS);
                        if(Integer.parseInt(res2) == 1){ 



                            JSONArray commentArray = json2.getJSONArray(KEY_COMMENT);
                            String comments[] = new String[commentArray.length()];
                            for ( int i=0; i<commentArray.length(); i++ ) {
                                comments[i] = commentArray.getString(i);
                            }
                            JSONArray numbersArray = json2.getJSONArray(KEY_NUMBER);
                            String numbers[] = new String[numbersArray.length()];
                            for ( int i=0; i<numbersArray.length(); i++ ) {
                                numbers[i] = numbersArray.getString(i);
                            }
                            JSONArray usernameArray = json2.getJSONArray(KEY_USERNAME);
                            String usernames[] = new String[usernameArray.length()];
                            for ( int i=0; i<usernameArray.length(); i++ ) {
                                usernames[i] = usernameArray.getString(i);
                            }

                            CreateCommentLists mycmlist = new CreateCommentLists(comments, usernames, numbers);
                            lstComments = (ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);

                            lstComments.setAdapter(mycmlist);








                            }//end if key is == 1
                        else{
                            // Error in registration
                            registerErrorMsg.setText(json2.getString(KEY_ERROR_MSG));
                        }//end else
                    }//end if
                } //end try

                catch (JSONException e) { 
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }//end catch    
            } 
        }


        new loadComments().execute();
   }
```

Here is my logCat

```
    07-17 17:07:13.436: E/AndroidRuntime(23880): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-17 17:07:13.436: E/AndroidRuntime(23880): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-17 17:07:13.436: E/AndroidRuntime(23880):    at android.widget.ListView.measureScrapChild(ListView.java:1163)
07-17 17:07:13.436: E/AndroidRuntime(23880):    at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1294)
07-17 17:07:13.436: E/AndroidRuntime(23880):    at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1155)
07-17 17:07:13.436: E/AndroidRuntime(23880):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:13011)
07-17 17:07:13.436: E/AndroidRuntime(23880):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4706)
07-17 17:07:13.436: E/AndroidRuntime(23880):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1369)
07-17 17:07:13.436: E/AndroidRuntime(23880):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:660)
07-17 17:07:13.436: E/AndroidRuntime(23880):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:553)
07-17 17:07:13.436: E/AndroidRuntime(23880):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:13011)
07-17 17:07:13.436: E/AndroidRuntime(23880):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChild(RelativeLayout.java:579)
07-17 17:07:13.436: E/AndroidRuntime(23880):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:392)
07-17 17:07:13.436: E/AndroidRuntime(23880):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:13011)
07-17 17:07:13.436: E/AndroidRuntime(23880):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4706)
07-17 17:07:13.436: E/AndroidRuntime(23880):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1369)
07-17 17:07:13.436: E/AndroidRuntime(23880):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1017)
07-17 17:07:13.436: E/AndroidRuntime(23880):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:555)
07-17 17:07:13.436: E/AndroidRuntime(23880):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:13011)
07-17 17:07:13.436: E/AndroidRuntime(23880):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4706)
07-17 17:07:13.436: E/AndroidRuntime(23880):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
07-17 17:07:13.436: E/AndroidRuntime(23880):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:13011)
07-17 17:07:13.436: E/AndroidRuntime(23880):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:812)
07-17 17:07:13.436: E/AndroidRuntime(23880):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:553)
07-17 17:07:13.436: E/AndroidRuntime(23880):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:13011)
07-17 17:07:13.436: E/AndroidRuntime(23880):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4706)
07-17 17:07:13.436: E/AndroidRuntime(23880):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
07-17 17:07:13.436: E/AndroidRuntime(23880):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:13011)
07-17 17:07:13.436: E/AndroidRuntime(23880):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4706)
07-17 17:07:13.436: E/AndroidRuntime(23880):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
07-17 17:07:13.436: E/AndroidRuntime(23880):    at com.navdrawer.SimpleSideDrawer.onMeasure(SimpleSideDrawer.java:443)
07-17 17:07:13.436: E/AndroidRuntime(23880):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:13011)
07-17 17:07:13.436: E/AndroidRuntime(23880):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4706)
07-17 17:07:13.436: E/AndroidRuntime(23880):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
07-17 17:07:13.436: E/AndroidRuntime(23880):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2162)
07-17 17:07:13.436: E/AndroidRuntime(23880):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:13011)
07-17 17:07:13.436: E/AndroidRuntime(23880):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1091)
07-17 17:07:13.436: E/AndroidRuntime(23880):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2505)
07-17 17:07:13.436: E/AndroidRuntime(23880):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-17 17:07:13.436: E/AndroidRuntime(23880):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
07-17 17:07:13.436: E/AndroidRuntime(23880):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4945)
07-17 17:07:13.436: E/AndroidRuntime(23880):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-17 17:07:13.436: E/AndroidRuntime(23880):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-17 17:07:13.436: E/AndroidRuntime(23880):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
07-17 17:07:13.436: E/AndroidRuntime(23880):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
07-17 17:07:13.436: E/AndroidRuntime(23880):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Please take a look at my answer. I have added some code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked if the `View` v that you return from your getView() method is null? Catching `Exception` catches all exceptions. Not really helpful in my opinion. What's happening here is that you have not initiated `Context ctx_invitation`. You should do this in the constructor. Now, since `ctx_invitation` is null, it causes a `NullPointerException` which is caught by the catch block. and `View` v remains null.

Change the constructor for CreateCommentLists:

```
public CreateCommentLists(String[] comments, String[] usernames, String[] numbers, DashboardActivity context)
        {
            super();

            listComments = comments;
            listNumbers = usernames;
            listUsernames = numbers;
            ctx_invitation = context;
        }
```

Change the following as well:

```
CreateCommentLists mycmlist = new CreateCommentLists(comments, usernames, numbers, DashboardActivity.this);
```

Comment: what should I set ctx_invitation too? Becasue when I try to place it in the CreateCommentLists mycmlist = new CreateCommentLists(comments, usernames, numbers); statement it causes an error

Answer (score 1):

I hope this might be help,

onPostExecute include (Inside AsyncTask)

ExampleAdapter sectionedAdapter = new  EfficientAdapter(ClassInfoThread.this,getBaseContext());
listView.setAdapter(sectionedAdapter);

and in your adapter class add this constructor

public ExampleAdapter(ExampleThread exampleThread,Context context) { 
 mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context); }

good luck.

Nandakishore P

Answer (score 0):

Now ctx_invitation is never assigned a value. You probably need a constructor to assign value to ctx_invitation.

Answer (score 0):

Googling around, looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8992353/418505) looks like you might be returning a null view from your adapter's getView method. Try tossing some breakpoints into the getView method and figure out where you are returning a null view.

Also, where are you storing the reference to the ctx_invitation in your BaseAdapter.

In the constructor you might want to pass that in